# Regex to match anything except for two words

Tags: regex

I've read through a lot of similar questions and I've tried a lot of things myself, but I haven't gotten a solution to this problem yet.  I have two strings - "foo" and "foobar" - that may come at the beginning of a line, may be enclosed by semi-colons, may come at the end of the line, or may be the only string in the line.  If my one-line text contains any of the following, I want to **not** match the line.

```
^foo$
^foobar$
;foo$
;foobar$
.*;foo;.*
.*;foobar;.*
^foo;.*
^foobar;.*
```

(^ denotes the beginning of the line, $ denotes the end of the line, ; is a literal match for a semi colon, and .* means any characters.)

For anything else, I want to match the line.  For example:

```
baz;quz        - regex should match the line
baz;foo;qux    - regex should not match the line
foobar;baz     - regex should not match the line
foobaz;bar     - regex should match the line
baz;qux;foobar - regex should not match the line
```

I have an application that will take an action if there is a match, and it will not take that action if there is not a match.  So I don't want there to be any match made if foo or foobar are contained.

The closest I have come up with so far is:

```
(;|^)(?!foo(;|$|bar(;|$))).*$
```

But this still matches baz;foo;qux because of the ";" at the beginning and ".*" at the end.  I haven't been able to figure out how to get it to work yet...

Thanks for any help you can give.

-Jon

Comment: Why not `(^|;)(foobar|bar)(;|$)` and invert your condition ?

Comment: I too would recommend inverting the condition - the match is much easier that way (and can be reduced to `(^|;)foo(bar)?(;|$)`)

Comment: My application does not really allow me to invert the condition.  Basically, if there is a match, then perform an action.  If there is not a match, do not perform the action.  It's possible I could work around that with your suggestions, but I don't think it would be easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this negative lookahead based regex for your matches:

```
^(?:(?!(?:;|^)foo(?:bar)?(?=;|$)).)*$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cP9yT9/3)

Comment: This seems really close.  It correctly does not match: baz;foo;quz.  But it incorrectly does not match: baz;sfoo;qux.

Comment: It's closer now.  But it does not match: ;baz;bar.foo;qux.  It should match that since foo or foobar are not by themselves within the semicolons.

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?!foo\b|foobar\b)(?!.*;foo;)(?!.*;foobar;).*(?<!\bfoo)(?<!\bfoobar)$
```

Try this.This should do it for you.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/45

Comment: I think this is very close.  The only thing is with \b, it is not matching the following: ;baz.foo.qux;  That should be matched.

Comment: @RustyLemur which string is not matching

Comment: ;baz.foo.qux; does not match.  It should match, because foo is not by itself within the semicolons.

Comment: That is because the above uses word boundaries instead of explicit semicolons.

Comment: The current expression does not match food by itself.